# What is the cleanest way to iterate over multiple outcomes when order matters (and assign each to a unique key)?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

Currently I attempting to write to an empty page in python, and using the built in dictionary in python. I am reading each line and if the line doesn't exist in the dictionary, I add it to the dictionary.

However I do not have the time to manually write every possible combination, but it is very important I am able to assign every possible combination its own unique key.

To solve this problem I attempted something like this:

```
while x <= number_of_outcomes:
        print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(value1, value2, value3, value4),file=outfile)
        nvalue1 = value1
        nvalue2 = value2
        nvalue3 = value3
        nvalue4 = value4
        nvalue1 = 0
        print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
        while nvalue1 == 0:
            ###print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(value1, value2, value3, value4),file=outfile)
            if nvalue4 == 2:
                break
            else:
                for i in setoftwo:
                    ###nvalue2 = nvalue2 + 1
                    ###print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
                    mvalue1 = nvalue1
                    mvalue2 = nvalue2
                    mvalue3 = nvalue3
                    mvalue4 = nvalue4
                    if mvalue2 == 1:
                        for i in setoftwo:
                            mmvalue1 = mvalue1
                            mmvalue2 = mvalue2
                            mmvalue3 = mvalue3
                            mmvalue4 = mvalue4
                            if mmvalue3 == 1:
                                for i in setoftwo:
                                    mmvalue4 = mmvalue4 + 1
                                    print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(mmvalue1, mmvalue2, mmvalue3, mmvalue4),file=outfile)
                            mvalue3 = mvalue3 + 1
                            print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(mvalue1, mvalue2, mvalue3, mvalue4),file=outfile)
                        for i in setoftwo:
                            mvalue4 = mvalue4 + 1
                            print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
                            
                    nvalue2 = nvalue2 + 1
                    print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
                for i in setoftwo:
                    nvalue3 = nvalue3 + 1
                    print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
                for i in setoftwo:
                    nvalue4 = nvalue4 + 1
                    print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(nvalue1, nvalue2, nvalue3, nvalue4),file=outfile)
```

I kept running into issues with the results printing the first value "0" for everything, I solved this by giving each nest its own "new version" of the value, then iterating that value.

However, at 4 values deep I realized there was no way I could possibly use this method for 256 values, at least not in my life time.

The goal is to end up with a dictionary where each key in the dictionary references to a string of numbers/letters , and each of those only have 1 of 3 options, and if the third option is choosen, no other number/letter may have that option.

So at 20 numbers long, there may be a definition like "01010201111110100000" or "ABABACABBBBBBABAAAAA" and it would be unique and defined by 1 key.

At the simple length of 4 I begin to notice I was missing values ( like 0112, using my method I could get 0221, but I would have to make an if statement after every 1 assignment that if the value is a 1, to iterate the next vale, and if it is a 1, iterate the next value ( that's already pretty wordy, and I knew right then going forward this couldn't work)

This has me mind blown because I have a hand drawn reference, of out to 8,  ( around 20 pages ) and decided maybe coding would be easier, but I am lost on how to easily move the "unique" value around so that for each unique value there is 0,1 or a,b in every possible combo.

2 values would print out
CA (01)
CB (02)
AA (11)
AB (12)
BB (22)
BA (21)
BC (20)
AC (10)

3 values would look like

CAA (011)
CAB (012)
CBB (022)
CBA (021)
AAA (111)
ABB (122)
ABA (121)
AAB (112)
... ( so forth) ...
BAC (210)
AAC (110)

Finally , in a perfect world if the key 11 or 111 or 1111 exist then the key 22, 222, or 2222 does not exist.  ( or visa-versa ) as they are equivalent, but in the worst case scenario, I can manually remove those from the dictionary after generating it.

I don't know how long the key length will end up being, I was actually trying to predict that by using smaller lengths and python, as I was drawing it out in hopes to find a pattern, but began missing key sequences and having to erase half a page to put it in the correct place (to attempt to visually see some kind of pattern )

For future purposes being able to have 2 or 3 unique characters in a long strand would be amazing, so any suggestions that allow for future  modifications to easily simulate how 2 or 3 unique characters play would be amazing.

I have a python text book from college in front of me, I have been up and down the search engines trying to see if some kind of probability and stat page would enlighten me, and I know my lack of experience is probably why I am failing to find the answer I am looking for, so if I missed an easy obvious solution , thank you for being kind enough to let me know.

Comment: Is `itertools.product()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Looking into this right now, looks promising

Comment: So I uh, couldn't quite make that work, it seems as if it erroneously places the good combos, in the "wronglist" that I now regret not naming "foo or bar"
"from itertools import *

def main():
    wronglist = {}
    for x in list(d):
        if (x[0] and x[1] == 'c') or (x[0] and x[2] == 'c') or (x[0] and x[3] == 'c') or (x[1] and x[2] == 'c') or (x[1] and x[3] == 'c') or (x[2] and x[3] == 'c'):
          y = y + 1
            keyid2 = str('num'+str(y))
            wronglist[keyid2] = {key}
            print(y)
        else:      
            correctlist[keyid3] = {key}

Comment: I didn't really read your entire question, can you simplify it to just the specific problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solves your base problem (one unique value):

```
from itertools import product

base_values = ['A', 'B']  # = 'AB' is also possible
unique_value = 'C'
key_len = n

keys = {
    ''.join(key)
     for key in product(base_values, repeat=key_len)
}
keys.remove(base_values[-1] * key_len)
keys |= {
    ''.join(key[:i] + (unique_value,) + key[i:])
    for key in product(base_values, repeat=key_len-1)
    for i in range(key_len)
}
```

Result for `key_len = 2`

```
{'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB'}
```

and for `key_len = 3`

```
{'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'BAA', 'BAB',
 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CBA', 'CBB'}
```

The more general question is a bit trickier. Here's a solutions (at least I think it is one):

```
from itertools import product, combinations, combinations_with_replacement, permutations

base_values = ['A', 'B']  # = 'AB' is also possible
unique_values = ['C', 'D', 'E']  # = 'C...' is also possible
key_len = n

keys = set()
for unique_len in range(min(key_len, len(unique_values)) + 1):
    uniques = combinations(unique_values, unique_len)
    base = combinations_with_replacement(base_values, key_len - unique_len)
    keys |= {
        ''.join(key)
        for ukey, bkey in product(uniques, base)
        for key in permutations(ukey + bkey)
    }
keys.remove(base_values[-1] * key_len)
```

But: The use of `permutations` is suboptimal, it produces multiple times the same key if `bkey` contains multiples, which then get unified by the set building. I know how to solve this in a messy way. I'll update when I come up with a better solution (provided you're interested).

This version is much faster but unfortunately not super readable:

```
from itertools import product, combinations, permutations

base_values = ['A', 'B']  # = 'AB' is also possible
unique_values = ['C', 'D', 'E']  # = 'C...' is also possible
key_len = n

def positioning(u_pos, k_len):
    b_pos = sorted(set(range(k_len)).difference(u_pos))
    u_len = len(u_pos)
    return {
        **{p: i for i, p in enumerate(u_pos)},
        **{b_pos[j]: i for i, j in zip(range(u_len, k_len), range(k_len - u_len))}
    }

keys = set()
for u_len in range(min(key_len, len(unique_values)) + 1):
    u_keys = [
        u_key + b_key
        for u_key, b_key in product(
                                combinations(unique_values, u_len),
                                product(base_values, repeat=key_len-u_len)
                            )
    ]
    for u_pos in permutations(range(key_len), u_len):
        pos = positioning(u_pos, key_len)
        keys |= {
            ''.join(key[pos[i]] for i in range(key_len))
            for key in u_keys
        }
keys.remove(base_values[-1] * key_len)
```

Comment: While it says to avoid saying thank you, I will start with doing just that, this is the kind of information I was looking for, I got so lost in trying to solve this using intertools I eventually burnt myself out. I do not recall what the ** symbol means, or why it is necessary, however it may be a crucial part in developing a clean solution. I have bookmarked this page, as to be honest with you, your understanding of python has reminded me of how little I know about the language. I will use this to learn, as I read through the intertools resource pages again.

Comment: @JonathanMartin Oh man, I totally forgot about your question: I shed quite some sweat over it :)) The `**` isn't that important, I've used it here only to unpack 2 dicts into a new one. Indeed, `itertools` has a lot to offer, I always find something new when I go through the docs.